# ObservableCollection.Remove - Cannot convert lambda expression to type because its not a delegate type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I stumbled across this very strange compiler behavior. I am trying to remove items from ObservableCollection based on some condition. Here is what I have in my code which throws error

```
public ObservableCollection<StandardContact> StandardContacts { get; set; }
....
StandardContacts.Remove(s => s.IsMarked); //Compiler Error
```

The error is as follows

```
Error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'RelayAnalysis_Domain.Entity.StandardContact' because it is not a delegate type
```

Surprisingly, the code below in the same method works

```
var deleteCount = StandardContacts.Where(s => s.IsMarked).Count(); //This Works
```

I already have following imports in my class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
```

This question may turnout to be silly, but it has had my head scratching.

Note: Even the Intellisence shows the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message unclearly states, you can't do that.
`ObservableCollection<T>` does not have a method that removes items that match a condition.  (unlike `List<T>`, which has `RemoveAll()`)

Instead, you can loop backwards through the collection and call `Remove()`.

Comment: I was really silly to post this question. I had similar method working in my another project and I thought is was bundled with default extension methods. But, actually I had custom defined this extension method for that project. So I just need to write a custom extension method in my current project.

Answer (score 4):

The remove method of Observable collection takes an input of type T (in this case StandardContract), not a `Func<T, bool>`. You may consider writing your own extension method for ICollection if this functionality will be useful to you:

```
public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)     {
var i = collection.Count;
while(--i > 0) {
    var element = collection.ElementAt(i);
    if (predicate(element)) {
        collection.Remove(element);
    }
}
```

Which would the be useable like so:

```
StandardContacts.RemoveWhere(s => s.IsMarked)
```